# How to measure if validator DID NOT propose a block in 4 seconds (so he should be slashed)?

Tags: consensus

I have read the documentation and from what I understood - if selected block proposer does not propose a block in 4 seconds, he is slashed.

But how do we “measure” that 4 seconds? If some peers will see the block, but others due to network connectivity problems will get it only in 6 seconds?
Is time somehow encoded into the block?

Comment: I think you've misread the documentation. Block proposers are encouraged to propose their block in the first 4 seconds of the slot they're attributed to, but there is no slashing for being late.

Comment: @upavloff Thank you. Still, then I didn't get the notion of this 4 seconds. Is it a "recommended" value which is never enforced?

Comment: Yes exactly. It is because after 4 seconds, attesters start to cast their attestation even if there is no block proposed.